# Most sort by mutual relationships neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to create a query in cypher but I have problems with one part this is how it should look

- Select one thread
- Get users that interacted with that thread
- Get top threads sorted by the number of users that interacted with both threads (The first- preselected one and second which I am looking for )

[image: Example Graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [aggregating function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) `COUNT` should help. Something like this:

```
MATCH (t1:Thread)<-[:USED]-(u:User)-[:USED]->(t2:Thread)
WHERE t1.id = 123
RETURN t1, t2, COUNT(DISTINCT u) AS cnt
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

The `DISTINCT` option, which incurs overhead, should only be used if it is possible for a `User` to be related to the same pair of threads multiple times.

Comment: Thanks, i will check that